# Javascript variable with function

Tags: javascript

I m new to javascript, and i m getting started learning.

I got small example from online:

```
<script>
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function(c) {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName();
</script>
```

Here i have raised one doubt, what is c here `fullName : function(c)`?

I check again without "c", there is nothing change.

May i know, what it is?

Comment: learn about arguments and how they are passed and what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it was said, in javascript functions arguments are always optional. For example:

```
<script>
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function(c) {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + c;
    }
};    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName("TEST");
</script>
```

The result would be: John Doe TEST (instead of John Doe).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript arguments are always optional, and you can see that the variable `c` is not used in your function's body. Then it is normal not to have any error.

Answer (score 0):

`fullName : function(c)` here c is an argument passed to this method which you can use it inside the function as you wish. But here its doing nothing as you ar enot using it

Answer (score 0):

first you should learn what is an argument and function? how arguments are passed in a function? 
what is the role of arguments in a function?

when you learned these topics, you wouldn't need any answers about the above question.